# How to display graphs on JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, graph, charts

I am working on huge data, is there any free java library which I can use to display charts and graphs on JSP pages with out java script, may be using JSP tags.

Comment: *"may be using JSP tags."*  An image should work.  Get a servlet hooked up to `JFreeChart` for the functionality behind the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use high chart along with your jsp pages link for the high charts is http://www.highcharts.com/